# Выровнять текст по центру картинки

Tags: html, css

Всем привет. Есть такой HTML код.

```
<img style="float: left;" src="img/contacts/our_adress.jpg" alt="Наш адрес" title="Наш адрес" width="20px">
<p>&nbsp; НАШ АДРЕС:</p>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image]

Текст выровнен по нижнему краю. Как сделать, чтобы он был  выровнен ровно по вертикальному центру картинки. Вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше через `inline-block`

**html:**

```
<img src="img/contacts/our_adress.jpg" alt="Наш адрес" title="Наш адрес"><span>НАШ АДРЕС:</span>
```

**css:**

```
img, span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

span {
    margin-left: 4px
}
```

[Смотреть здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/0b7umm5s/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `vertical-align: middle;` для `inline, inline-block` элементов.

```
<img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img/contacts/our_adress.jpg" alt="Наш адрес" title="Наш адрес" width="20px" />

<p style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">Наш адрес</p>
```